# Active Directory LDAP issue driving me nuts

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap-query

I have written a Java application to retrieves selected AD user account attributes to try and match the company's HR employee records with AD. Everything works perfectly except the attribute"accountExpires" always returns null in my code. When I check a sample of the same user accounts using the Apache LDAP viewer (Eclipse plugin) I can see a date/time and long value.

Here is my code that works for everything except retrieving the "accountExpires" attribute.
    package com.acne.LDAPRealmTest;

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.naming.NameClassPair;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.BasicAttribute;
import javax.naming.directory.BasicAttributes;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;
import javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext;
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapContext;

public class LDAPCtxTest {
    DirContext ctx = null;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    int counter=0;
    SearchControls controls;
    private final static long DIFF_NET_JAVA_FOR_DATE_AND_TIMES = 11644473600000L;

    public LDAPCtxTest() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Active Directory search test"); 
            Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();

        /*  Begin by defining the environment properties and getting the InitialDirContext class object initialized.
          */ 

        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "connection_string"); 
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CN=LDAP_USER,OU=Service Accounts,OU=System Administration,DC=acne,DC=com,DC=au");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "test01");
        env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");

        ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
          // Create the search controls          
          controls = new SearchControls(); 

          //Specify the attributes to return 
          String returnedAtts[]={"sn","name", "accountExpires", "sAMAccountName", "department","telephoneNumber","userAccountControl","cn","pwdLastSet","accountExpires","objectcategory"}; 
          controls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts); 

          //Specify the search scope 
          controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE); 

          //String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl=512))";
          String searchFilter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl=512))";
          //Specify the Base for the search 
          String searchBase = "DC=acne,DC=com,DC=xx"; //this doesn't seem to work so replaced with empty string which is ok
          //initialize counter to total the results 
          //controls.setCountLimit(100); // limits the search result to 200

          File outFile = new File("C:\\temp\\", "ldaptest.txt");
          BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outFile));
          bw.write("Counter,sAMAccountName,userAccountControl,name,AccountExpiry\n");
          NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ctx.search("", searchFilter, controls); 
          //Loop through the search results
            while (answer.hasMoreElements()) 
            {
                SearchResult sr = (SearchResult)answer.next();
                Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
                Attribute attrAccountControl = attrs.get("userAccountControl");
                Attribute attrName = attrs.get("name");
                Attribute attrAccountExpire = attrs.get("accountExpires");
                Attribute attrSAMAccount = attrs.get("sAMAccountName");

                counter++;
                sb.append(counter+","+attrSAMAccount.get(0)+","+attrAccountControl.get(0)+","+attrName.get(0)+ ","+attrAccountExpire+"\n");
                System.out.println(counter + " " + attrSAMAccount.get(0) + "..." + attrAccountControl.get(0));
            } 
          bw.write(sb.toString());
          bw.close();
          System.out.println("The End");
          ctx.close();
          System.out.println("LDAP connected ok");
    } catch (NamingException ne) {
        System.out.println("LDAP connect FAILED");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }       
}

private Date getDateTimeFrom(String adDateTimeStr) {
    long adDateTime = Long.parseLong(adDateTimeStr);
    long milliseconds = (adDateTime / 10000) - DIFF_NET_JAVA_FOR_DATE_AND_TIMES;
    //long milliseconds = (adDateTime / 10000) - DIFF_NET_JAVA_FOR_DATE_AND_TIMES;
    Date dateVal = new Date(milliseconds);
    return dateVal;
} 


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new LDAPCtxTest();
}
```

}

I have looked at various threads relating to LDAP query especially relating to accountExpires, and looked on Microsoft site which lists LDAP attributes. It appears that there is nothing wrong with the attribute name I have specified above and I have not found anyone else with similar issues. I am not sure what else could be the problem.

Comment: Since "accountExpires" is an operational Active Directory attribute, I tried the following with NO success:  

        String returnedAtts[]={"*","+"};

Comment: Note: I have managed to retrieve the attribute, following switching from LDAPS to LDAP protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: The attribute "accountExpires" was accessible once I had switched from LDAPS to LDAP. Ideally I prefer, for security reasons, to connect over LDAPS but Active Directory administration is not my area and I will let that decision sit with AD gurus.

Also note I was able to access this (operational) attribute without appending it to returnedAttrs "+".

Comment: To wrap up this conversation finally I would like to say that there might have been a firewall or port filtration configured for LDAP and LDAPS separately which explains different query response. Only that I would have expected tighter control on non secure port which was not the case.